# Euler 13: Unexpected result while trying to concat multiple String

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to solve [this problem on euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=13):

> #### Large sum
>
> Problem 13
>
> Work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred 50-digit numbers.
>
> ```
> 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
> 46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
> 74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
> ...
> 53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690
> ```

I'm trying to concat all the lines into one big chunk of line, however I'm not getting the expected result, can anyone see what I did wrong here?

```
var fs  = require("fs");
var total = "\n";        
let m1 = fs.readFileSync('lines.txt').toString().split('\n').forEach(line => {
    total += line;
})
console.log(total)
```

output:

> 53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Strings aren't numbers.

Comment: @trincot The numbers are definitely larger than 2^53, aren't they? This question is an exact dupe of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678303/extremely-large-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: Yep, but the question is not asking to do arithmetic on them *in their totality*.

Comment: Your code for concatenating the strings does work, although it is unnecessary to split on the line breaks and then rejoin the strings. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Works here, there must be something wrong with your `lines.txt`.

Comment: ...the whole enterprise makes little sense though. Why do you want to lump these numbers together?

Comment: @georg, read the challenge...

Comment: @trincot: I did. The question stands.

Comment: Well trying to concat the lines is the wrong approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to the last part of your question: the reason the output looks like that may be caused by the format of the input file. Possibly it has `\r\n` characters as line break sequence, so if you split the text by `\n` only, the `\r` will still print. As a result the last line could "overwrite" all previous lines in the output.

You could solve this by changing the `split` argument as follows:

```
.split(/\r?\n/)
```

To the problem you try to solve:

- Trying to concatenate the lines is not going to solve the problem at hand. This way your are not doing anything with the numerical values that would bring you closer to the solution.
- The question needs to know the last 10 digits of the sum. There is no attempt in your code to provide that. The reason for this 10 is that summing numbers with 50 digit-precision is beyond the capabilities of JavaScript, so you really need to do something with this.

Some hints:

- Use `slice(-10)` to get the last 10 character of a line
- Convert strings to numbers before doing any arithmatic
- Use the modulo operator (`%`) to get the last 10 digits of any sum

Comment: OP specifically stated "What I'm trying to do is to concat all the lines into one big chunk of line". Even if his approach to the problem is incorrect, that's not what he's asking. He's asking why the lines are not concatting when running his code.

Comment: tl;dr don't solve the euler problem and give him the answer, give him the answer to the specific question he asked.

Comment: Second that. That's not what they asked.

Comment: If he were asking for the answer to problem 13 directly, then his question would be broader basically just asking "How would I solve this problem". That is *not* what he did. He is specifically having trouble concatenating strings together in his code, and that is what he is asking help for. If he really does want the solution for problem 13 just posted here, then I suggest he broaden/edit his question.

Comment: Updated my answer to deal with the problem with the seemingly truncated output.

Comment: ty appreciate it

Comment: @trincot Yes, my question was how to concat them into one big string, and it did :)

Comment: You're welcome ;-) Note that if that is the only thing you wanted to do, then it is no different from removing the new lines. So instead of `split`, you could have used `replace(/\r?\n/g, '')`, and the return value would be the long string.