# how to split a large integer in javascript

Tags: javascript

All:

How can I correctly turn a VERY VERY LARGE number(at least 32 digits) into a character array?

For example:

var n = 111111122222233333334444444445555555555666666677777777788888888888

Thanks,

Comment: you can't - because your example is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` - note: in Chrome and Node you can `var n = 111111122222233333334444444445555555555666666677777777788888888888n; n.toString().split('')` - **not the *n* at the end of the number**

Comment: Where is the number coming from?  Easiest solution would be to make it a string from the start if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with very large numbers in javascript (anything greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`) you'll have to handle the number differently than you would a normal integer.

Several libraries exist to help aid in this, all of which basically treat the number as a different type - such as a string - and provide custom methods for doing various operations and calculations.

For example, if you only need integers you can use [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js). Here's an implementation below:

```
const bigInt = require("big-integer")

const largeNumber = bigInt(
  "111111122222233333334444444445555555555666666677777777788888888888",
)
const largeNumberArray = largeNumber.toString().split('')
```

Also check out some other stackoverflow questions and resources regarding handling big numbers in Javascript:

npm's big-number-> https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-number

[What is the standard solution in JavaScript for handling big numbers (BigNum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/what-is-the-standard-solution-in-javascript-for-handling-big-numbers-bignum)

[Extremely large numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678303/extremely-large-numbers-in-javascript)

[What is the standard solution in JavaScript for handling big numbers (BigNum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072307/is-there-a-bignum-library-for-javascript)

http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber

http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the string representation of a number by calling `toString` and then convert it to a character array using `Array.from`.

```js
var number = 123456789;

console.log(Array.from(number.toString()));

var bigNumber = "34534645674563454324897234987289342";

console.log(Array.from(bigNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't breaking the maximum integer value for JavaScript, then you can use:

```
var n = 123456789;
var l = n.toString().split('');
```

That will get you an array where the first value is the `1` character, the second is the `2`, etc.