# What is the correct way to return a large decimal to TypeScript via an API?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This question is about serializing large decimal data from C# to TypeScript, without using strings/ manual conversions for every property if possible.

I have a TypeScript/Angular application taking data from a C# API (.NET Core).

The application needs to return large decimal numbers to the UI, but those numbers are getting truncated on serialization/deserialization to TypeScript.

e.g.

> API sends................-> 1,099,998,888,755.5676667
>
> TypeScript shows....-> 1,099,998,888,755.5676

I have seen [posts](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/javascript/number.html) about using [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) or [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/), but they haven't included the issue of serialization. Having tried Big.js, that doesn't stop the truncation on converting to TS either.

It seems we might have to make a separate string field and manually convert to/from big.js when getting the data down/sending it up, but that seems a big ugly.

What is the correct way to do it please?

**Example Class**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
}
```

**Example TypeScript Class**

```
export class MyClass {
  public amount: Big; // have tried 'number' and 'any', but they don't work.
}
```

**Example API Call (Angular)**

```
getAmount(inputVm: InputVM): Observable<any> {

    var url = this.baseUrl + 'api/ControllerApi/ActionName';

      // Data already truncated at 'tap'
    return this.http.post<MyClass>(url, inputVm).pipe(
        tap(resp => {
        return resp; // Already truncated!
        }),
        catchError((e: any) => {
          return throwError(e);
        }));
  }
```

Comment: That number is too large to be represented as a number. Why not transfer it as a string?

Comment: If that's the answer, then I'm happy to go with it. Just didn't want to fudge it, if there's a "right" way to do it. It also adds some faff as I have a lot of those fields, not just the one (example was simplified, for ease of explaination).

Comment: If you are not going to do mathematical operations with those numbers, then you better just treat them as string data. Think of those digits as a name that happens to be all digits or as a phone number. However, if you are going to use mathematical operations, then you should be using a library to support big numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I need to do some maths with them, otherwise I'd have happily send them down as strings.

Comment: Then send as string -> convert using a big number library. They should all have some way to read a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extremely large numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678303/extremely-large-numbers-in-javascript)

Comment: @Reactgular- NOT a duplicate and this question was well researched. I am aware of the conversion libraries. The issue is finding a neat way of getting the from the API without using lots of extra string properties/ conversion code. Also, the numbers are decimals, so the BigInt type isn't any good for me.

Comment: @VLAZ Yep. That would work. I was really looking for a neater way though, as that would double the number of properties and lead to 100's of lines of converting code on receive and send of data. Just feels like there should be a neater way.

Comment: @HockeyJ I don't know your stack and I don't use much of .NET but from Java I'd assume that you can just annotate your big number properties in a special way `@JsonSerialize(using = BigNumberSerialiser.class) private float someNumber` and then all your special logic would be in `BigNumberSerialiser`. Although since all your logic is that it should be a string, it will likely be easy - there should be something for "serialise as simple string" but can't remember. You could also just make your own class `MyNumber` and have a serialiser for that and it would be used automatically for the type.

Comment: Since `decimal` is always 16 bytes you could use base64 to encode them as strings.  It would take 24 bytes to encode them.  You could use the hex encoding for simplicity and each would take 32 bytes.  There is no 128 bit number type in JavaScript so you’d need to use a big number library once sent.  I think most should be able to read in a hex string or byte array.