# Sorting lines by first numbers

Tags: javascript, sorting, discord

leaderboard.txt content:

```
3, 503167934726311936
8, 737050574519967865
-10, 737050574519967865
23, 737050574519967865
19, 737050574519967865
-4, 737050574519967865
-14, 737050574519967865
27, 737050574519967865
```

unfinished javascript:

```
leaderboard = (fs.readFileSync('leaderboard.txt', 'utf-8'))
    //sorting leaderboard by number before comma
    fs.writeFileSync('leaderboard.txt', leaderboardSorted, 'utf8')
```

the result should look like this:

```
-14, 737050574519967865
-10, 737050574519967865
-4, 737050574519967865
3, 503167934726311936
8, 737050574519967865
19, 737050574519967865
23, 737050574519967865
27, 737050574519967865
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Also explain exactly what you want to do such as what the final output should look like and any edge cases you can think of.

Comment: @apena I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

After you have [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) up your string input and [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)'d it, you can pass a custom comparing funciton to the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method, which will only compare the first element of each item. Then you can [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them back together to write to the file.

```js
const leaderboard = "3, 503167934726311936\n8, 737050574519967865\n-10, 737050574519967865\n23, 737050574519967865\n19, 737050574519967865\n-4, 737050574519967865\n-14, 737050574519967865\n27, 737050574519967865" // same as readFileSync

const data = leaderboard.split('\n').map(item => item.split(', ').map(parseFloat))

data.sort(([score1, id1], [score2, id2]) => score1 > score2 ? 1 : score1 < score2 ? -1 : 0)

leaderboardSorted = data.map(item => item.join(' ,')).join('\n')

console.log(leaderboardSorted)
```

Comment: I just realized that the last 2 digits are always rounded. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: The largest number the JS can hold with normal floats is ` Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, or  9007199254740991. Basically anything more than 10 digits of precision is going to get messy. Think of another way of storing the data, you probbaly can store as a string, or you don't need that much precision. Or look into bigint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678303/extremely-large-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: Decided to slice the ID's in the middle and connect them later.