# MySQL JavaScript query replaces last digits of a number with 0

Tags: javascript, mysql, replace, output, digits

I have this code (shown below) that connects to the database, and then runs a SQL query that selects all the values (bigint snowflake IDs) in the "id" column that are also IN the array written inside the query. Once that's done, it logs the result to the console.

For some reason though, it seems to round off the numbers, or at least replace some of the last digits with 0. I'm trying to find out why and how to fix this, so help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "botproject"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    con.query("SELECT id FROM xplevel WHERE id IN (718141588043202731, 294126883694444544, 685325127373553689, 307409641262940160, 478536470081175562);", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      
    console.log(result);
 
    });

});
```

The expected output would be this (the exact same values that were put in the query's array):

```json
[
  RowDataPacket { id: 294126883694444544 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 307409641262940160 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 478536470081175562 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 685325127373553689 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 718141588043202731 }
]
```

But the actual output that I'm getting is this:

```json
[
  RowDataPacket { id: 294126883694444540 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 307409641262940160 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 478536470081175550 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 685325127373553700 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 718141588043202700 }
]
```

**EDIT:**
Note that it doesn't do this when running the query directly in the mysql terminal as such:

```
mysql> SELECT id FROM xplevel WHERE id IN (718141588043202731, 294126883694444544, 685325127373553689, 307409641262940160, 478536470081175562);
+--------------------+
| id                 |
+--------------------+
| 294126883694444544 |
| 307409641262940160 |
| 478536470081175562 |
| 685325127373553689 |
| 718141588043202731 |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This looks to be some kind of rounding/precision error.

Comment: Try casting the number to BigInt: `SELECT id FROM CAST(xplevel AS UNSIGNED) WHERE...`

Comment: @ZephDavies Using `SELECT CAST(id AS CHAR) AS id FROM . . .` works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of JavaScript IEEE754 numbers.

You can do simple test in browser console:

```
let a = 685325127373553689
a
685325127373553700 //prints rounded value
```

To deal with such data in JS you need to disable automatic conversion into numbers and make it return you the data as strings. Or convert it into new BigInt type, or use some 3rd-party libraries for large-numbers processing ([Extremely large numbers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678303/extremely-large-numbers-in-javascript)).

Comment: Thank you! Converting it to a string by using `SELECT CAST(id AS CHAR) AS id FROM . . .` works like a charm.

Comment: That's quite dirty to make MySQL cast datatypes to fool JS :) I'd better look for options how to solve it on JS-side. But anyway if it works then why not.

Comment: I realize this question is almost two years old, but I'd like to clarify that I did look for better options, and I found out that adding `supportBigNumbers: true` in the object passed in the mysql.createConnection method will convert those big numbers into strings, fixing the inaccuracy issue.

Comment: @KingTMK that sounds like a cool alternative solution. Why don't you submit it as an answer?